# Show sequence $a_n = \frac{n^2}{n+1}$ is divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

> Show sequence $a_n = \frac{n^2}{n+1}$ is divergent

My thinking is, we shall show $a_n$ is unbounded, and hence cannot be convergent.

Suppose $M \in \mathbb{R}$ is an upper bound for $a_n$.

Choose $N \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $N > 2M$ (Do I need to justify why I can do this? If so how?)

Notice, for all $n > N$:

$$\frac{n^2}{n+1} > \frac{n^2}{n+n} = \frac{n^2}{2n} = \frac{n}{2} > \frac{N}{2} > M$$

Hence we cannot find an upper bound for $a_n$, and so not convergent.

Comment: Haven't you seen the equivalents ($\sim$)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two minor comments.

**One**, very minor:

You can justify the existence of $N$ by recalling the Archimedean property of integers.

---

**Two**, slightly less minor:

You don't need to phrase your proof as a proof from contradiction. In fact, it is usually preferred to not do so if possible, because proofs by contradiction are usually slightly less elegant and slightly harder to follow. Your proof can be rewritten ever so slightly like so:

> Let $M\in\mathbb R$. Then, there exists $N \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $N > 2M$
>
> Notice, for all $n > N$:
>
> $$\frac{n^2}{n+1} > \frac{n^2}{n+n} = \frac{n^2}{2n} = \frac{n}{2} >
> \frac{N}{2} > M$$ and therefore, $M$ is not the upper bound of the sequence. Since $M$ was arbitrary, we conclude the sequence does not have an upper bound.

This is true even more in general. Many many proofs by contradiction, especially by less experienced students, are not *really* proofs by contradiction, and most of the time, they can be rewritten into a more direct form.

As a rule of thumb, you can spot them because they look something like this:

- We are trying to prove that the statement $\exists x\in A: P(x)$ is not true.
- Let $x\in A$.
- Assume $P(x)$ is true.
- **Something something.**
- Therefore, $\neg P(x)$.
- This is a contradiction with the assumption $P(x)$.
- Therefore, $\neg P(x)$.
- Therefore, $\forall x\in A: \neg P(x)$, qed.

You might notice there is a bit of duplication in the proof above. We are concluding $\neg P(x)$ **twice**. And sometimes we are. However, be careful, it's very important what happens in the "something something" stage of the proof. There are two options:

1. If the assumption $P(x)$ is used inside the *somethingsomething* part of the proof, then the proof is *inherently* a proof by contradiction. An example of this would be the standard proof of infinitude of prime numbers. In that proof, we specifically use the assumption that there is only a finite number of primes, and then construct a new number that is coprime to all of them.*
2. However, the cases I am describing are such that the assumption $P(x)$ is **not used** in the *somethingsomething* part of the proof. In that case, the same proof can be rewritten simply as:

- We are trying to prove that the statement $\exists x\in A: P(x)$ is not true.
- Let $x\in A$.
- **Something something.**
- Therefore, $\neg P(x)$.
- Therefore, $\forall x\in A:\neg P(x)$, qed.

* Now, technically, even **that** proof can be rewritten into a more constructive form, but in that case, the rewrite would be very extensive and would not improve readability.

Comment: Does Cantor's diagonalization argument really use the assumption that the list is an enumeration of $\mathbb R$ though? Is it not along the lines of, give me any sequence of real numbers, and I can find you a real number not in the sequence?

Comment: @AndrewZhang Good point, I guess that one also falls into the second category :). Maybe the infinitude of primes would be a better example.

Comment: I think Euclid's proof of the infinitude of primes also falls into the second category! Give me a finite list of primes $p_1,\dots,p_n$. Then $x = p_1\cdots p_n + 1$ has no prime factors in the list, implying the existence of other primes. Edit: I guess the version presented on Wikipedia is indeed a true proof by contradiction: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction